# Apache Lucene / Elasticsearch snapshot restore with merge

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, pylucene

I have successfully snapshotted and restored data multiple times in ElasticSearch (ES) using its [APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/modules-snapshots.html). But now I want to merge two snapshots in ES or directly in Lucene to restore a 'larger' chunk of data.

Details:
I take weekly snapshots of my data and as soon as restoration is done I delete the index so essentially the workflow looks like this

```
Create index abc
Snapshot index abc
Delete index abc
-----
Create index abc (again)
Snapshot index abc
Delete index abc
```

I have looked around but it seems there is no way to do that but [those posts](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/restore-from-backup-and-merge-with-newer-data/28760/5) are an year old so wanted to reach out to the community again.

Also if not in ElasticSearch is there a way to do this Lucene directly and then configure ES to use 'new combined' index for restoration?

My language of choice for development is Python so I am looking into PyLucene as well but haven't explored it much yet.

Comment: Can you explain why you delete your index `abc`?

Comment: @Val I delete the index after snapshotting. So the new data is not incremental data it is entirely new batch of data/metadata. I tried looking into the files and incremental thing works only if I keep snapshotting the same index without deleting the index in between.

Comment: @Val to the newer comment: I am using ES as an ad-hoc analysis store. I don't need 'historical' data in ES all the time so delete the older index. But sometimes I need 'historical' data to analyze the trend in past as well.

Comment: @Harshdeep could you not use an index alias, to restore old indices,but query against all of them including your newer ones?

Comment: @IanGabes that is the only solution which looks decent to me at this point. I was hoping for a merging approach so that I don't have to write a very smart programmatic (abstraction) layer for restoration which renames while restoration then creates an alias.